# Mathematical standard term for a function of (different) operator arguments

Tags: linear-algebra, functions, soft-question

In quantum mechanics, one often considers functions of linear operators, like

$$f(A,B) = A\cdot B + e^A \cdot B^2$$ where $A,B$ are linear operators. In physics this often causes confusions, as some people try to apply arguments from functional analysis, which only hold for functions of complex numbers.

So, for didactical reasons, I'd like to know, if there is an alternative, phrase for $f$, which is more specific than "function". I have some terms in mind, like "function of (non-commuting) operators", but it would be nice to have something catchier with a smoother sound.

Comment: How about nonlinear operator?

Comment: @TooOldForMath Thanks, but my purpose is not to distinguish it from functions which are linear in operators, but from the corresponding, nonlinear function of two *numbers*, e.g. $f(x,y)=xy+e^x y^2$ where $x,y\in\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: Yea that's why I used the word *operator*. Because it really is an operator from a product space of linear operators to a space of operators But whenever one says operator one thinks of linearity so thats why I added "nonlinear".